# Should posts saying "don't do what you're asking" be flagged as "not an answer"?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, declined-flags, not-an-answer

Several days ago I reviewed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5484150 from LQP. It was decided 50/50 as OK/Recommend for deletion by reviewers, so it was left intact.

For me this answer looks like advice "Don't do it" rather than answer to original question; that is, it is a comment posted as an answer, and thus should be deleted.

So I flagged that answer as "Not an answer", but this flag was declined.

Can you please explain me, why that answer is not "Not an answer"?

I searched through meta, found several similar questions like this [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer) but that doesn't answer my question, as I think I understand differences between attempt to answer the question and Not an answer.

Comment: That post is **most definitely** an attempt to answer. It is not a 'thank you' or 'have you solved this yet?' or 'how do I cross-pollinate my tomatoes?' post.

Comment: Although in this case I can see, a little, why there is some confusion. But as you say yourself, it is an answer that comes down to *do not do that, because a, b or c*.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer

Comment: Ok, now I have a question "What to do when my question's title changed to reflect just one possible answer", or "What to do if I said in question that possible duplicate question didn't help but still receive it as a duplicate". Anyway, thanks @MartijnPieters I see your point

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can see a little where you are coming from. The post does try to answer the question, though, albeit in a roundabout way. It is essentially saying: *don't do this*, and that's a [valid *type* of answer too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer).

It *would* have been better of as a comment perhaps, but that's an action that the review queue could have taken. The community decided to leave the post be and *not* delete it.

So, borderline better-of-as-a-comment, but the NAA flag should not be used for that; keep those for the *how do I adjust the bearings of my filing cabinet wheels?* type of answer posts.

Comment: But wait, then how will anyone be able to tell me the best anagram for *Oh a belching bigoted Irish just now fed my Westie a flan?* :-/

Comment: Please keep in mind that the accepted answer recommends, in the general case, to **also answer the question, even if you advise not to do so**. That's actually important if doing so is not categorically bad.

Comment: @Deduplicator: which is why in this case it is a borderline case, and the community review was divided.

Answer (score 5):

If it says "Don't do it because..." and lists the reasons then that's an answer.  Vote up if helpful, down if not.

Without the "because", then just "Don't do it" is not an answer (and not a very helpful comment, either).

Comment: If there is no answer to the question, it is not an answer, even if it has reasons for not doing it.  That would be a comment.

Comment: @TomWilson I disagree. It is often the most valuable type of answer. More discussion on the subject [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer).

Comment: Perhaps I am overly sensitive to the ubiquitous "you are not doing it right" answers that show up on many reasonable Rails questions<g>.  I agree that consistently flagging "you shouldn't do it that way" answers is not the intention of the flagged status.