# What constitutes an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, not-an-answer

A fairly consistent question that gets raised on MSO is what constitutes an answer.  This takes several forms:

- Why was my NAA flag declined? ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268369/289086))
- These comments should have been an answer. ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277039/289086))
- answers that appear to address the question. ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277045/289086))

This appears to be related to a hesitancy of mods to delete any post that has some modicum of value.  So, what constitutes an answer? Do posts that 'address the question' but not answer it qualify as answers?

Comment: There are at least to cases that I find troubling. One is when I have a partial answer. The other, even more difficult case, is when I have a comment that is too long or involves code. We really need a third type of response that does not claim to be an answer but is intended to be of permanent value and may be longer and more complicated than a comment.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268438/

Comment: @RobertHarvey "Attempts to communicate with another user." - the "your SQL has an injection flaw" is such an attempt and should not be an answer.  It doesn't matter if the original post is a question or an answer.  Writing answers that 'address the question' without answering the problem posted in the question itself are borderline "attempt to communicate with another answer."  At issue here is where does that line get drawn?

Comment: @MichaelT - No.  "your SQL has an injection flaw" is an attempt to communicate with future readers, so they don't cut and paste an injection flaw.

Comment: @RobertHarvey http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: There you go...

Comment: @RobertHarvey and when the question meets those bullet points or bolded text, one would tend to expect that a NAA would have some action taken.  In the situation of "there is a security hole in your code", it doesn't fundamentally answer the question and may be considered a commentary on the question. It shouldn't be suggested the be posted as an answer (this isn't Code Review). Likewise, posts that *are* tangents or fail even a plain english reading should be examined to see if it is in fact, not an answer...

Comment: ... while it isn't black and white, and you are probably not going to get meta posts about declining something that is #808080.  However, strictly adhering to #000000 being black and not taking action on things that are #0A0A0A is at issue.  The question really is one of "what is an answer".  If someone flags a post as NAA and it matches the criteria in the help center, but is declined (or suggests posting answers that violate those points)... well, we're in meta now for that reason.

Comment: **Rule of thumb:** *If a moderator cannot figure out whether it's NAA by looking at the answer only, it's not NAA.*  Answers which require looking at the question to determine whether or not they're actual answers are better served by casting a custom moderator flag instead of an NAA flag.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it should then be considered that the text for NAA should be updated to state instead: "This was posted as an answer, but is nonsense, asks another question, or is just a 'thanks'.  For [all other issues](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), use a custom flag."  However, that doesn't take into account that mods are suggesting using answers as durable comments or suggesting that the criteria for an answer is "appears to addresses the question" rather than "fundamentally answer the question".

Comment: Does this constitute a comment? Or is it a question?

Answer (score 16):

A key component to Stack Overflow is that questions have answers.  They have **detailed** answers (as described in the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)).

> This site is all about **getting answers**.  It's not a discussion forum.  There's no chit-chat.  Just questions ... and answers

In [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) from the Help center:

> #### Answer the question
>
> Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

Note the bit "The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”."

A comment that is *"You have a massive SQL injection in your post"* is **not an answer**.  It may "address the question", but it is not answering the problem of "how to do ${something}".

Just because a post is related to the question does not mean it is an answer. Having posts that are addressing the question show up as answers increase the amount of noise in the system and make it that much hard to actually *find* the answer in the list of 'answers'.

This is the key component that separates Stack Overflow from forums and discussion sites.  You go to a question that is "how do I do XYZ" and all of the answers ***should*** be about how to do XYZ.  If the question is about understanding some concept, all of the answers ***should*** be about understanding the concept (not how to implement it with some tool).

By suggesting that posts that are "addressing the question" constitute answers, Stack Overflow reduces its utility, makes it less appealing for the experts, and that much more difficult to find answers.  The combination of these things makes it less useful as a brand and less useful as a site to go to.  Sure, the OP gets a bit more information, but as has been mentioned time and time again, the site is tangentially designed for the OP - it's *really* for the next hundred people who have the same question and find the question and answers.

So...

- An answer must answer the question.
- Answers may continue to address other parts of the question, ***if*** they also answer it.
- Comments may address the question.
- A post that doesn't answer the question increases the noise on the site.

Consider the comment:

> @phpUser SQL has significant security holes and is open to SQL injection.  You should fix it using a prepared statement.

If this is an acceptable answer rather than a comment on a post that contains such a security hole... consider the situation where phpUser wrote an answer instead and this was some code for some other question.

This shows that such a comment is an attempt to communicate with another user on another post.  It is not answering the question.  It may happen that the user is someone who posted the question, or posted an answer.  It should not be an answer.

Posts that appear to address the question but don't answer the question are not answers.  They are instead posts that fall into the category of "Attempts to communicate with another user" which is a valid reason to flag as *not an answer* (NAA) and delete or convert to a comment.

If the above comment *is* a valid answer, I've got a lot of php questions to go answer. If this would be frowned upon by the mods and would be receiving NAA flags from the community, then one should consider if posts that "address the question" are indeed answers.

The help center provides guidance as to why answers can be deleted in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers):

> Answers that do **not fundamentally answer the question** may be removed. This includes answers that are:
>
> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> - exact duplicates of other answers
> - barely more than a link to an external site
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

Please note that the emphasis is in the original.  Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed.  This is the wording.  It is not "answers that don't address the question may be removed" - they must answer the question or they may be removed.

#### Related discussions:

- MSE: [Is “Don't do it” a valid answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8891/213963)
- MSE: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/213963) (with the apples and answers taxonomy)
- [Should answers that do not answer a question be preserved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252404/289086)
- [Should posts saying "don't do what you're asking" be flagged as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268283/289086)
- [How should I flag an answer that CLEARLY doesn't even remotely relate to the question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254558/289086)
- [Should a "related reading" answer be flagged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268902/289086)

Comment: People are often told that comments are ephemeral, and may be deleted without notice.  Where should,er, information that is likely to be quite useful to the hundreds of people reading through the answers go, if that information does not happen to include an answer?  ("You have a massive SQL injection in your post" is an O.K. example of such information).

Comment: @psr yes, they are. And the ideal situation would be to write an answer that follows the guideline of "The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”." But just because a comment is ephemeral and points out some key issues (that aren't answering the question) doesn't mean that just because it addresses the question it would be a good answer. Answers should *always* answer the question; not provide insight, or a hint, or answer something else that the person thought they read.

Comment: @pnuts I couldn't say for sure... though note the list is "includes" rather than "a complete list of reasons".  I would suspect its in part because it really isn't that good of a question and isn't encouraging good answers. The answer to your question is likely found in [Should I flag answers consisting only of “No” or “Yes”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110165/213963). The better approach would likely have been to rewrite the question so it wasn't a "yes/no" question and then fully answer it.

Comment: @pnuts There's no code in there to worry about rewriting - its an example.  I'm a proponent of closing the question quickly (easier said than done), and then rewriting it (which may include adding hypothetical code).  I do note that this is [controversial](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276425/289086) (+16/-11) in some circles. Yet, once the question is closed, more drastic measures can be taken to make it into a good one that can get reopened. It just happens that in this case, someone went for the 'write code for someone ex nihilo based on the spec in the question' which is... meh.

Comment: Hmm, there is a lot in here I actually agree with, but I feel like a lot of your frustration is hinged upon "Posts that appear to address the question but don't answer the question are not answers.", and that I don't agree with.  That's a *very* general description, which could encompass many answers that do answer the question but are just plain incorrect.  What you are describing are not **good** answers.  But also, just because something doesn't fit the *very specific* confines of the NAA flag doesn't mean it doesn't deserve to be deleted/downvoted to oblivion.

Comment: @Ajean They could be a valid answer on CodeReview, where the charter is to review all parts of the code. However, if I answer a question about the sql injection in the code presented when the question is instead "how do I redirect to a new page after a post" - that doesn't answer the question and instead presents noise that someone coming to the question has to filter out to actually find the answer they came there for. I am concerned about the increased noise - moderators suggesting non-answers being posted and refusing to delete non-answers. With more noise comes reduced participation.

Comment: ... the alternative to the NAA flag is to down vote and delete by 20k users (or 10k users on the question). The down votes on answers are often difficult to muster (this often takes place on meta, and people complaining about the meta effect) (and then people complain about lost reputation - compare deleting via NAA with 3+ score grandfathers the reputation in, possibly a better end user experience). I contend that the *least* painful way to accomplish a better signal to noise ratio is for moderators to not be as strict in NAA (and instead go by the help center guidelines).

Comment: @MichaelT You have to keep in mind that the mods don't see the question when they are given NAA flags to examine, so they have absolutely no idea on the technical accuracy or relevance to the question. I'm just saying that the NAA queue for the mods is not the best avenue for the things you're describing.

Comment: @Ajean I've had that discussion [before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268369/289086). And while the interface for mods may be lacking, it doesn't mean that NAA should be interpreted as strictly as it is currently.  Nor does it suggest that mods should be suggesting that commentary on questions be posted as answers (that don't answer the question).

Comment: Well, you are entitled to your opinion, and the desire to clean up the site is truly a worthy one, I'll support that!  However, I don't feel that a slightly looser interpretation of "an answer" than yours means that mods are "suggesting that commentary be posted as answers".  That's putting words in their mouths.  I think most NAA flags are truly NAA and get accepted, and what you are describing is a tiny sliver of potential answer issues.

Comment: @Ajean in [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277039/289086), "In this case, while not a complete answer; posting an answer comprised of those two comments would be a good idea: It addresses the question; gives good information about what would be an issue with what the user is doing, and provides durability that otherwise might not be there with a comment." - note that it doesn't answer the question.  A mod is suggesting that for durable "important" comments, they should be posted as answers instead. I believe this fundamentally conflicts with the help center guidance...

Comment: ... and linked a few other instances of this approach being taken ("answer appears to address the question").  The comments in there lead to this Q&A trying to get a better clarification from the moderators about what they believe constitutes an answer.  I've provided initial material from the help center to state my point. Until people understand what is (and what is not) an answer, and the documentation is in agreement with that understanding, doing NAA flags can be a crapshoot when cast on answers that happen to address a point in the question without answering the question itself.

Comment: It pretty much just comes down to the fact that you just plain disagree. You want all answers everywhere to be complete (no partial answers!), and the mods are less stringent.  I'll just let you complain at them in peace, then.

Comment: One of the best answers I've had on SO didn't answer the question at all, it bypassed the question and and suggested a different approach. Great for me in that specific instance but probably less that ideal for others searching on the question. That's a longwinded way of saying that 'answering the question' may be too restrictive - 'solving the problem' may be more useful

Comment: @PerryW I've [done things in the past](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/183982/revisions) where I've rewritten a (poor) question to one that states the problem better and then answer *that* (and [written about how to do an Atwood transform](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6744/40980)). Part of the context for this post is another meta post where some comments about the security of the code in the question were brought up, and that was suggested to be an answer - even though it didn't answer the question or solve the problem at hand.  ...

Comment: ... note the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing a good question addresses your point of "The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer." - so you still did answer the question / solve the problem in that situation. But [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981440/using-a-database-query-result#comment42497358_26981440) isn't an answer to the problem, but a comment.

Comment: If an answer isn't allowed to say "don't do that for this reason; do this instead", then how is a user with reputation less than 50 supposed to deal with questions that show evidence of an XY problem on the asker's part?

Comment: @tepples answers are *certainly* allowed to say "don't do that for this reason; you solve your problem by doing ${something else}" - thats described in how to answer in the help center.  However, answers to the question of "how do I use the results of a database query" should *not* be "you have the possibility of SQL injection in the code" - because that doesn't answer the question or solve the problem of the problem - thats a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981440/using-a-database-query-result#comment42497358_26981440).

Comment: I was confused as to whether that line in the help center was something you wanted to abolish through this question. Your reply solves my XY problem issue, leaving a second: What should sub-50 users horrified at the insecure approach described in a question do?

Comment: @tepples I think that the information provided in the help center mentioned in this question is well written and reflects good policy. Unfortunately, people going by the material provided in the help center and using that to flag NAA are often having their flags declined - I would be pleased with a change to the wording of the flag. Furthermore, there seems to be a difference between the guidance in the help center on asking questions and the actions of moderators dealing with custom flags. I would like a better understanding of the correct way to handle incomplete, duplicate, and non answers.

Answer (score 6):

This constitutes a bad answer. [With a random link thrown in for good measure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277052/)

Comment: See what I did there? An answer takes many forms, but answers that look like this one are invariably bad.

Comment: @Servy Took your idea and reintegrated it with what I intended. Cheers :)

Comment: I like how it turned out.

Comment: Downvote or flag, downvote or flag???

Comment: @bluefeet The irony is strong in this one, it's bad and good at the same time :)

Comment: Which is exactly why I've done nothing @slugster. This post is so confusing but also so clear.

Comment: @bluefeet Why choose?