# Are "Your code works fine for me" answers acceptable?

Tags: support, answers

I'm sure that this has been asked before, but I couldn't get any similar results through the search.

2 days ago I flagged [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27104220/1317805) as "Not an answer", simply because it doesn't answer the question - all it does is state what was already stated in the comments, which is that the code provided in the question already works, and provide a JSFiddle demo to prove it.

This flag was disputed, so earlier today I flagged it once again, this time to be reviewed by a moderator (as you can't flag the same post twice for the same reason), with the comment:

> I had previously flagged this as "not an answer", but my flag was disputed. I can't flag the post as "not an answer" twice, so as the answer is still here: this post isn't an answer, it's simply an "I tried your code and it works fine for me" comment.

However my second flag has now been declined by a moderator.

Is it okay to post answers which realistically say no more than "your code already works for me"?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't expect this sort of post to require moderator intervention, which is likely why the mod declined it.

Comment: @Makoto of course, but once a flag has been disputed you can't flag again for the same reason.

Comment: I wouldn't call that an answer. The short question is *"What am I doing wrong?"* The short answer is *"It works fine for me."* Which isn't really answering the question and would be more grounds as a comment.

Comment: You have an answer to your current question, however I'd be inclined to also ask "Why was my flag denied". Although it might just be that age old disagreement on what scenarios certain flags should be used. Logically, your flag was perfectly legit, as the answer was not an answer, and a comment on the answer stating as such has 4 upvotes..

Comment: This was indeed asked a while ago, but is now on Meta.SE: [Are "works for me" answers valid?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118992)

Comment: I'll point out that a *disputed* flag usually means that the answer/question was edited to fix the problem you flagged, before the flag got reviewed.

Comment: related: [What constitutes an answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277048/what-constitutes-an-answer) _'By suggesting that posts that are "addressing the question" constitute answers, Stack Overflow reduces its utility, makes it less appealing for the experts, and that much more difficult to find answers. The combination of these things makes it less useful as a brand and less useful as a site to go to...'_

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Stating that you cannot reproduce the problem described in the question is not an answer.  It's an indication that the question is lacking in sufficient information.  Usually this is because some of the code is missing, the posted code does not accurately represent the author's real code, or there are other environmental issues outside of the code that are causing the problem.  There are close reasons specifically for questions like this that don't contain enough information to reproduce the described problem:

This reason is generally the most applicable:

> This question was caused by a problem that can **no longer be reproduced** or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Other close reasons that may also apply more in certain other situations are:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest **code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

(emphasis mine)

or potentially just:

> unclear what you're asking
>
> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Posting an answer to say that the question does not contain enough information to be answerable is not an answer to the question.

Comment: As a moderator, I'm not going to remove an answer that addresses the question and says the code works fine. If you want to flag it as 'not an answer', have at it, [but it will be declined if I'm processing it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277958/16587).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Then you're not doing your job as a moderator.  It's your responsibility to enforce the rules as they are laid out, not to do whatever you want regardless of what the rules are.  If you don't like SE's policy that answers need to *answer the question* then you can propose a policy change here on meta.  If the community agrees with your proposed change and supports, it, then you can act accordingly.  If they don't, then it's **your job** to enforce the community's supported policy regardless of your personal views.

Comment: @Servy Regarding environmental issues, I disagree that the question is "lacking in sufficient information". Threading ones can be more or less random in their behavior. In fact, many hard to debug problems are like this.

Comment: @Servy: It's never a moderator's job to mechanically respond to flags. We have human moderators so that they can use their judgement to [fix exceptions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), not so that they can enforce rules by rote. In this case, the post survived a low quality review (3 to 1) 2 days ago. So there's at least some disagreement there.

Comment: @JonEricson The point of moderation is not to achieve consensus. There are rules there which make sense and should be followed.

Comment: @Jon Ericson: Of course, a human moderator is expected to use his judgement from case to case. But here, George Stocker said that he will *generally* decline such flags, in other words, he *does* mechanically respond to flags but using the opposite of the default rule.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, that is plain abuse of your powers.

Comment: @holger if you're interested in the actual nuance of my answer, see the answer I posted.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: *Not* doing something is an abuse of powers? That's a new one.

Comment: I'm taking the following definition: "Abuse of authority, in the form of political corruption, is the use of legislated or otherwise authorised powers by government officials for illegitimate private gain." The mod doesn't agree with something (private), and actively disengages its enforcement.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão So what do I gain (what is my 'private gain') by not marking the flag helpful and deleting the answer?

Comment: I was referring to the "As a moderator, I'm not going to remove an answer that addresses the question and says the code works fine." As Servy pointed out, and as I see it, by purposely not enforcing it you are putting your opinion on this matter above others, which is not what mod position are for. In any case, your answer puts in in much better terms.

Comment: It is a pity that we cannot revisit the moderators' act from time to time. I am not against George as he is usually doing good job regardless this mistake, but in general, I see moderators (some other) doing pretty selfish moderation, rather than following their boss: the community. If I tried to bring this up particularly about a moderator, I would be shot in the head, demotivating myself from trying to bring my concerns up. It is a shame that some moderator actions show that they can rule the "rules" over rather than them following the community consensus.

Comment: @MichaelMyers [declining a flag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277923/are-your-code-works-fine-for-me-answers-acceptable/278030#comment122219_277924 "'it will be declined if I'm processing it'") qualifies as doing something, _using mod powers_. Let's not pretend that we speak about simply abstaining of action

Comment: Don't be ridiculous, @lpapp. Folks bring up issues with moderator actions *every day*, and they're generally addressed humbly and politely. Granted, if you go around calling people "despotic" that's not likely to get you taken seriously - but, that's true regardless of who you're name-calling.

Comment: @Shog9, that comments sadly shows exactly what, in my not so humble opinion, the fundamental flaw is: moderators always find excuses in the packaging and the way things are said, not _what_ is being said. "Thank you" for the confirmation that you do not care about the _what_ at all, just how. In other words, you become personal rather than professionally objective. This makes me (and likely many other) people completely hopeless to improve this site. It goes without saying: just continue banning us for our opinion, maybe 10 years? 100 years?

Comment: @lpapp Your extraordinarily hyperbolic way of trying to make your point is certainly not helping the conversation along. If you want a discussion, start a real question here on meta that doesn't use the phrases "shot in the head" or "banning us for our opinion" without evidence that such things actually occur. *Anyone* is going to become defensive and dismissive when you start with this kind of hostility.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: again, _that_ is exactly the problem. You also concentrate on the how, and not _what_ I am trying to write. This has been happening all the time. It is an easy excuse for "escaping" from the real objective responsibility. You can go on and on, and not solve the objective issue, but that is pretty counter-productive. As far as evidence goes, please visit the site in my profile just for one of those.

Comment: @lpapp Yes, it's called "having a conversation". Of course the way in which you say something is going to impact how it's received. You can try to live in a fantasy world where that doesn't happen, but out here in the real world, it makes a difference. Are you saying you wouldn't treat an email from a stranger differently based on whether it started with "Hi, please help" or "Hey asshole, do your job"?

Comment: @ChrisHayes: that is exactly what I have been writing for ages, yes. I concentrate on the objective merit, not on love is in the air. That is kind of the point for being professional... Fwiw, I find your and some moderators' style awkward just as you may find mine, but I do not mind that, really.

Comment: @lpapp You're different from probably 99% of people out there, then. Congratulations on your tolerance, but if you intend to make any difference with the 99% of people who aren't like you, I'd suggest learning *why* people are being dismissive, rather than saying "you're not listening to my message" without making any changes to the way you deliver that message.

Comment: Heh, 99% is like you; that is IMHO unreal an assumption. I agree that the majority is unprofessional, but that is sad that it is even true on Stack Exchange. Fwiw, I got a moderator warning today for being "agressive, harrassing, attacking, and what not" without clear explanation just because I linked to a community consensus on meta. That was pretty personal from the moderators and in no way professionally objective, but I do not mind as long as it was objectively true, however that was not. The point I am trying to make is do not expect people's style being the same.

Comment: @lpapp It's not about style, it's about not being rude. Personally I consider it far more "unprofessional" to be needlessly rude than to be offended when somebody's being a jerk. But it's clear you have no intention of listening to advice that's intended to further your own chances of a meaningful discussion, so I give up.

Comment: It's not personal, @lpapp; the comment I referenced came to my attention because it got flagged by the community and deleted by the system. It's my job to investigate claims of moderator abuse - even if most are groundless, the danger is too great to not follow up.

Answer (score 21):

Regarding flagging that answer as not an answer, it was disputed (by the community) and declined (by a diamond moderator), rightly so.

Simply put, it is an answer.

Question: What's wrong with my code?

Answer: Absolutely nothing is wrong with your code.

It's an answer to the question that's asked. That doesn't mean the question is an especially good question (and most times, it probably isn't), but it's still an answer.

We have a very specific criteria for [flagging a post as 'not an answer'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer).

That having been said, [sometimes as moderators, we disagree](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118993/16587). That's ok, we're human and we have different takes on the subject.  Our actions are binding, so it's important that we are able to completely defend every action we take -- especially if that action is to remove content from the site.  One moderator may be able to justify removing content that another moderator simply wouldn't.

So let's look at the content of the answer.  As "your code works" answers go, this one is especially good.

> > I had tried the above code and it works fine for me.
>
> ```
> function printIndex() {
>
>   var data = "Hello  123  123";
>   var  searchText='3  1';
>   var position1=data.indexOf('3  1');
>   var position2= data.indexOf(searchText);
>
>   alert("Position 1 : "+position1+" position2 : "+position2);
> }
> ```
>
> Please refer this [Working JSFIDDELE](http://jsfiddle.net/NWWL4/25/)

Not only do they provide an answer (the code works), but they then provide the working code in its entirety and they provide a fiddle that shows it in action.  You simply can't get any better than that for a 'your code works' answer. The spelling wasn't especially good, but otherwise it was a good answer.

Some people may claim that it should be a comment?  There are times that's true.  Generally if you have a one line answer, it could very well be a comment. But what about this answer? This answer has working code and a link to a Fiddle -- would you want to see that in a comment?

Probably not.

So, while there are specific cases where you should flag 'this works!' as 'should be a comment', there are other times where it's inappropriate to do so, simply because the answer provides useful content outside of the 'this works' statement.

Your best bet in this situation would be to vote/flag the question for closure as either a "typographical error" or that the user has not provided enough information to solve their problem (since they see a problem no one else can see).

Going after the best answer that could be given under the circumstances is punishing the wrong person; we don't want to discourage people from giving good answers simply because the person who asked the question didn't know what they were doing.

[I've answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23612432/the-sails-js-controller-action-is-called-twice-during-every-http-request/23621164#23621164) in the past using the very same methodology I present here.

[Previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251609/should-old-high-rep-link-only-accepted-answers-be-deleted).

Comment: There’s a huge difference between the following two statements: (1) On my particular development environment your code did not exhibit the problem. (2) There is absolutely nothing wrong with your code. Dev environments are vastly different, and I see more "your code works fine for me" answers where this is the explanation than where it isn’t. I sometimes ask the answerer to delete them,with a link to this question. If you back your statement that there’s nothing wrong with the code with more much substantial arguments than just "runs fine here", it’s an answer.

Answer (score 21):

It is not an answer, and neither of your flags should have been disputed/declined.

The question is "Why am I getting -1 for `position2`?" and the answer does not answer that question. It's basically saying "You aren't getting -1 for position2" which the OP clearly is, or at least thinks they are. That's not an answer. It's a (useful) comment, indicating that the OP needs to revise the question or retest their code.

An *answer* would at least try to address why the OP might have been getting -1 despite the code presented not replicating it:

> The code in your question shows "9" twice (see the snippet below), so if you're seeing -1 for `position2`, the code you're running isn't quite the same as the code in your question. Here are some things to look for:
>
> - There are many kinds of spaces in Unicode, perhaps one of your strings is using an unusual space
> - There are invisible characters in Unicode, perhaps your `searchText` string has one or more of them hidden in it
> - Perhaps your `searchText` has spaces at the beginning or end that you missed
> - Perhaps you changed your code but forgot to reload it (or saw a cached version)
>
> [Stack Snippet would go here]

...and so on. That's speculating, but in a helpful way, and does at least try to answer the question (which is the chief criterion for answers). Copying and pasting the code into a fiddle isn't an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would humbly chime in that this falls into the "pick-your-fights" bin. *Technically* you are perfectly correct, the "answer" is hardly an answer.

But is this something we see *that* often? Well, probably not too often when the code works as is.

A lot of times the moderators intuitively see that there is effort in an answer, so.. better left alone.

There will be times when the author just wants validation more than a real answer. I'm guessing this doesn't happen more than 5% of the time.

Comment: Wanting validation?  That doesn't sound like it'd be on topic here at all.

Comment: @Makoto - touche touche, i stand corrected.  I dunno, my main thought was one could just downvote it since it's a useless answer.

Comment: It's not *totally* useless. If OP thinks the problem is in the code they posted and someone else comes and says the code works fine, they will then know that they are looking in the wrong place for the problem. Hardly makes it worth posting an answer, and should be a comment, but not quite worthless.

Comment: "But is this something we see that often?" <- yes, I see probably 1 of these a week in a slow moving tag like Sass.  Equally annoying are questions where the provided code works fine but the answerer attempts to fix it anyway with sometimes less efficient code that gets the same results.

Comment: Coffee I think I'm with you here - I've found that there is considerable dispute on meta regarding the use of the NAA flag, so I usually reserve it for things like "anybody answer this question yet?" instead of fighting flag policy battles.  On other egregious things, I downvote.