# answer as copy of the question, flag declined

Tags: support, declined-flags

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26956728/1033581) gives a piece of code and states:

> Using the above code ***doesn't work***

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39438864/1033581) gives the pure exact same code and nothing else. It doesn't event attempt to answer because it contains the question itself and nothing else.

I tried to flag with an explanation:

> This post is strictly identical to the question code sample. So it's not an answer, it's purely duplicating the question with no additional explanation whatsoever.

The flag was declined with no explanation on why it was declined.

Comment: @Cerbrus, it appears the OP used a custom mod flag here, in addition to the NAA flag previously reported. I'm not sure the duplicate is appropriate.

Comment: @Cerbrus no, question is different. It's an answer with absolutely nothing in it.

Comment: The answer is the same: OP didn't use the right flag. It _is_ an attempt at answering. A poor one at that, but still can be seen as an attempt. "Very low quality" could have been approved, but a downvote would've been the safe bet.

Comment: Closely related: [Are "your code works fine for me" answers acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277923)

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I can't see anything implying the code works for the answerer, though.

Comment: Did you cast a NAA flag or did you go with a mod flag first thing?  I fail to see why a NAA flag would not work and I think that may be why it was declined as it was something the community could handle.

Comment: @NathanOliver I tried NAA first, then it said "you already used this flag", so I tried moderator.

Comment: @Cœur _"It's an answer with absolutely nothing in it."_ But it's still "an answer". If I'd answer a programming question with a recipe for a good apple pie, it'd still be an answer. It'd just be VLQ. (And should be deleted)

Comment: @Cerbrus there was no VLQ flag to choose from in the list

Comment: @Cœur: Then downvote it...

Comment: "If I'd answer a programming question with a recipe for a good apple pie, it'd still be an answer" I really would like to hope that's sarcasm. [Sadly, I suspect it isn't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308459/603977).

Comment: OK. It passed [review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15508480). I did notice there that the question code and the answer code do differ so I can see why they said looks ok.  Normally in cases like this I leave a comment as *While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.*

Comment: @JoshCaswell: That's just how the "NAA" flag is interpreted by the mods. If it in any way attempts to answer the question, NAA doesn't apply. NAA is meant for gibberish / "I'm having this problem too", etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not the moderator who declined your flag, but I think I can surmise why.

Here's the code sample from the question:

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
 return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;
}
```

And here's the code sample from the answer:

```
class Scene2ViewController: UIViewController {

    //blah blah code

    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .LightContent
    }
}
```

Other than the seemingly superfluous class definition, notice the return statements. The answer omits the `UIStatusBarStyle` enum name from the expression. For all the moderator knew, omitting the enum name *could* have had a different effect, and so they chose to err on the side of caution and not assume the code was in fact functionally equivalent, and so declined your flag on those grounds.

Of course, knowing Swift I know the code *is* functionally identical, and I likely would have handled your flag differently had I seen it. Often we'll ask around if we need a second opinion on custom flags like this on questions and answers, but don't rely on this happening. I think this is one of the *rare* cases where I'd actually recommend that users who know better, with the right privileges vote to delete such answers — moderators tend not to act on flags that have a basis on technical accuracy in general.