# Should an answer explaining the background that led to the problem be flagged as Not An Answer?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

I saw [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23059596/) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaOBB.png)) which contains the information needed to solve the problem stated in the question, but it is not addressing the OP's question, or trying to phrase his answer as such. It is more just "commenting" why the solution the OP is looking for, is a bad style by whoever designed the system.

So I would see it as comment and thus "Not an answer".

Am I right?

Comment: Does it somehow try to answer the question, even when bad? Then don't flag. If you need only a little bit of technical knowledge about the issue to answer that, then don't flag.

Comment: @juergend: I would say It isn't trying to answer the question, but it does. What he does is kind of: "I really ddon't like the system. there are many bad thinks. For example you have to do...[solution for the op]... what is really pointless and should be changed." But he doesn't state, that `[solution for the op]` is the solution, he just drops it without commenting it in that context.

Comment: The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19033027) is just above that reply and was recognized as such by both the OP and other appreciative readers. The reply you linked to is nothing more than a rant from a frustrated user. I would likely VTC this citing *'I'm having this problem too'*.

Comment: @Jeeped What means "VTC"? But yeah, thats what I thought too. But wasn't sure, as it still contains information, that are usefull to solve the problem. And I was not sure, in how far an answer has to be presented in an answering way for SO.

Comment: @Zaibis - VTC = *Vote To Close* (which you cannot perform on a answer, only a question so I really don't know what I'm talking about)

Comment: @Jeeped ah ok, So.... you would suggest, this is not an answer? or where you just in another topic with your mind?

Comment: @Zaibis - Yes, it is not an answer. As a rant it should have been left as a comment to the actual answer (the general content of which it duplicates). It certainly adds nothing to the thread.

Comment: @Jeeped: Well, the audits were of different opinion. " not an answer – Zaibis 1 hour ago   declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer "

Comment: A bad answer tends to start with a bad question.  You have to really work on not finding the answer to this one, googling the compiler error message is enough.  So users tend to post a non-obvious answer.  This question needs to be deleted, it is superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, absolutely. It doesn't answer the question in a useful way; it is commentary on the problem. That should be clear to anyone who can read English.

On the other hand, since it *incidentally* contains the solution to the problem, reviewers likely thought it would be worse to delete it than to leave it. They don't necessarily see the entire context that you saw when flagging: that there is a much earlier, clearer, accepted, and upvoted answer that contains the same information and more.

Armed with that fact, it's easy to recommend deletion, and users with more than 20k (such as myself) can vote to delete negatively-scored answers outside of the queue.

I would recommend downvoting any answer that you're flagging as NAA as a matter of course -- a non-answer is certainly a poor one, and it may encourage reviewers to look more closely. (You'll get the rep you expend back when the answer is deleted.)

NAA flag handling [reveals a split of opinions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268369/why-was-this-not-an-answer-flag-declined) in the users here [that has come up quite frequently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277048/what-constitutes-an-answer). There's no clear path to tread.